# cropping image and save to specific folder in sdcard (Android)?

Tags: android, imageview, sd-card, crop

I've image has been crop. I want that image save to folder (sdcard)...I've already done crop image and show to imageview, but my problem is, I don't know how saving image crop to sdcard ?

here is my code has success to crop an image..

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

if (extras != null) {               
    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
}
```

where I can add the code to save an image that have been cropped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this way:

> ```
>  Bundle m_extras = data.getExtras();
>  // get the cropped bitmap
>  Bitmap m_thePic = m_extras.getParcelable("data");
>  String m_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
> File m_imgDirectory = new File(m_path + "/Images/");
> if (!m_imgDirectory.exists()) m_imgDirectory.mkdir();
> OutputStream m_fOut = null;
> File m_file = new File(m_path);
> m_file.delete();
> String m_fileid = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
> m_file = new File(m_path, "/Images/" + m_fileid + ".png");  
> try
> {
>     if (!m_file.exists()) m_file.createNewFile();
>     m_fOut = new FileOutputStream(m_file);      
>     Bitmap m_bitmap = m_thePic.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
>     m_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, m_fOut);
>     m_fOut.flush();
>     m_fOut.close();
>     MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
>             m_file.getAbsolutePath(), m_file.getName(), m_file.getName());
> }
> catch (Exception p_e)
> {
> }
> ```

Add below permission in manifest file.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```