# Android app Image is not saving in specified Sd Card folder after Crop, Showing empty folder

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdcard, android-image

I am capturing the image using camera in my android app.

then Cropping the image.

after Cropping saving the image in specified folder.

Folder is creating, But image is not saving in the folder.(Its Empty)

Help me to resolve it

code  I have used,

[link referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14360091/4447803)

```
                    if (extras != null) {

                            Bitmap photooutput = extras.getParcelable("data");
                            // Camera Output

                            if (pick == 1) {

                                viewImage.setImageBitmap(photooutput);


                                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                                File m_imgDirectory = new File(path + "/WallPaper/");

                                if (!m_imgDirectory.exists()) m_imgDirectory.mkdir();

                                FileOutputStream m_fOut = null;
                                File directory2 = new File(path);
                                directory2.delete();
                                String m_fileid = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
                                directory2 = new File(path, "/Wall/" + m_fileid + ".png");  


                                try
                                {
                                    if (!directory2.exists()) directory2.createNewFile();
                                    m_fOut = new FileOutputStream(directory2);      
                                    Bitmap m_bitmap = photooutput.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                                    m_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, m_fOut);
                                    m_fOut.flush();
                                    m_fOut.close();
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
     directory2.getAbsolutePath(), directory2.getName(), directory2.getName());
                                }
                                catch (Exception p_e)
                                {
                                }
                        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Android KitKat and above, it is impossible for an app to save a file onto the SDCard.
Check this [Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/14VUiIgwUjY/UsxMYwu02z0J)

**UPDATE**
Save an image to internal storage:

```
public static Uri saveImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    Uri uri = null;
    try {
        String name = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        //you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
        File f = new File(getImagesDir() + File.separator + name);

        f.createNewFile();
        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bitmapToByteArray(bmp));
        // remember close de FileOutput
        fo.close();

        uri = Uri.parse("file://" + f.getPath());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return uri;
}

public static String getImagesDir() {
    String rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    rootDir = rootDir + "/MyApp/Media/Images";

    // Create directory if not existed
    File dir = new File(rootDir);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }

    return dir.getPath();
}
public static byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

**UPDATE 2: missing code added**

Add the following permissions to your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: then how to save the image in my sdcard or internal memory folder.

Comment: what are all the permissions need to add here

Comment: i have added this permission in manifest still not working . folder also not creating

Comment: Do you get any exception?